# Adding to many worksheets

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access-2010, addition, worksheet-function

I want to add one worksheet in Excel with programming in Access. After the following code line, I get nine more worksheets (Statusbericht0, Tabel2, Tabel3, Tabel4, Tabel5, Tabel6, Tabel7, Tabel8, Tabel9, Tabel10).

```vb
xlWB.Worksheets.Add.name = "Statusbericht0"
```

But it is important to say, that I add some more worksheets before this code line to.

Comment: You will have to show the whole code otherwise it's not possible to say where the error lies.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the sheet before you name it. In order to name it, you need to keep a handle on it. Like this:

```
Dim NewSheet As Worksheet
Set NewSheet = xlWB.Worksheets.Add
NewSheet.Name = "My new sheet"
```

Comment: `xlWB.Worksheets.Add.name` works as `Add` returns a worksheet object (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheets.add)